# Excel Power Query From Folder

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking for some advice if the following is feasible.

Each week I have a number of csv files being saved to a folder. What I would like to achieve is to combine these files in to one table in Excel so that I can then check, review and amend the data in the table if required. This is preferred to opening and amending each of the csv files. When new files are added to the folder the following week I would like to append these to the existing table in Excel such that I do not over write the existing data in the table. If I use the 'From Folder' feature to combine the csv files I would loose the previous weeks amendments when the entire table is refreshed.

At this time I would welcome views on if this is possible or if I need to consider a different approach.

Thanks
SH

Comment: Power Query is primarily for aggregation and analysis of data, not addition/editing of it (because in PowerBI that's all you need). However it is possible to set it up to track and maintain local changes/additions of data to a Query that is output to a table in Excel. Depending what kind of changes you are making though, this can get kind of tricky. I would say it depends on what your data is and how you're changing it if it makes more sense to try and retain those changes in the Excel file or to edit the .csv source data.

Comment: Is there any key fields through your csv data? Will you ever need to modify these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to compare a current table of records held in the speadsheet to the list of files in the folder using a Merge Anti Right join. This provides a list of 'New' files only which i can then append to the bottom of the current table using vba